# In rspec, what is the correct way to pass a class name to a shared_example?

Tags: rspec

In an rspec test suite that tests a module are tests to evaluate the behaviour of classes that include the module. Below is a rough example to demonstrate.

```
describe "MyMod" do
  module MyMod; end 

  shared_examples_for "a class" do |klass|
    it "includes the module" do
      klass.included_modules.include? MyMod.should be_true
    end 
  end 

  describe "when included in a class" do
    before(:each) { class C; include MyMod; end }
    it_behaves_like "a class", C
  end 

  describe "when extended in a class" do
    before(:each) { class C; extend MyMod; end }
    it_behaves_like "a class", C
  end
end
```

The problem that I have is the class `C` is not defined when `it_behaves_like` is executed, producing an error:

```
`block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant C (NameError)
```

What is the correct way to define a class and pass it to a shared_example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the arguments to the shared example are evaluated before the `before` blocks are even executed. You need to either pass your shared example the symbol `:C` and have your example turn it into a constant or you need to pass a block which sets some other variable, as in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block

Comment: Yes thanks, I suspected as much from reading the book. I tried `let(:klass) { Class.new.extend(MyMod) }` which work for `extend` but gives an error for `include`: "private method `include' called". I think I'll just use a different approach!